# How can I deconstruct a function call when passing it as an argument to another function

Tags: c#

I would like to pass a function that returns two values to another function that expects the same two values as parameters. In the example below I want to pass GetNum To GetLine.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetLine(GetNum()));
    }   
    public static (int,string) GetNum() => (5,"five");
    public string GetLine(int n , string s) => $"{n} {s}";
}
```

Is there any C# syntax that can help me?

Comment: I think he actually wants to deconstruct tuple in function argument (instead of function body). The wording he used to ask the question is confusing a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions only return one value (i.e. one `Type`), in this case `GetNum` is returning a `ValueTuple<int, string>`.

One way to allow the `GetLine` method to work with the return type of `GetNum` is to write an overload of the method that takes a `ValueTuple<int, string>` and returns the result of passing `Item1` and `Item2` to the original method:

```
public string GetLine((int, string) t) => GetLine(t.Item1, t.Item2);
```

Now you can use the return value of one method as an argument to the second:

```
var result = GetLine(GetNum());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetLine(GetNum()));
}   
public static (int,string) GetNum() => (5,"five");
public static string GetLine((int, string) a) {
    var (number, text) = a;
    return $"{number}, {text}";
}
```

Why does this work? The `(int, string)` in argument of `GetLine` function is actually a type, just like `float` or `double`. Therefore it makes no sense to actually deconstruct it in place. When writing function argument, you are not expected to write any logic there - you cannot for example increment a number there. You are expected just to list argument types and names of the arguments.

Comment: It doesn't make sense if you have a tuple parameter, but it does make sense if you have multiple non-tuple parameters like in OP's example. Just because it makes sense doesn't mean C# lets you do it though. It seems like the only option at this point is to do it as you've outlined. It would be nice if the other way worked though if you have an existing method without having to write an overload like `public static string GetLine((int number, string text) a) => GetLine(a.number, a.text);`

Comment: @itsme86 nevermind -- I think i just don't understand your comment

Answer (score 3):

There is no C# syntax that will do literally what you want. A method that has two parameters, such as your `GetLine()` method, needs to have two arguments passed to it, and C# doesn't provide a way to deconstruct tuples except into specific *variables*. Since arguments to a method are just values (with the exception of by-reference arguments), there's no variable into which to deconstruct your tuple.

There are *lots* of different ways to do something similar. However, IMHO the closest to what you want to do would look something like this:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static TResult CallDeconstructed<T1, T2, TResult>(this (T1, T2) tuple, Func<T1, T2, TResult> func)
    {
        return func(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
    }
}
```

I.e. an extension method you can call on the tuple, which will pass the tuple's individual values as separate method arguments to the provided method. Used something like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    //Console.WriteLine(GetLine(GetNum()));
    Console.WriteLine(GetNum().CallDeconstructed(GetLine));
}
public static (int, string) GetNum() => (5, "five");
public static string GetLine(int n, string s) => $"{n} {s}";
```

All that said, I'm not sure that any of the alternatives, including the above, is really all that much better than writing the intermediate code at the call site:

```
(int n, string s) = GetNum();
GetLine(n, s);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a template for that -- it looks like :

```
 public static string GetLine(Action<string, int> passedProc, otherParms) // etc
```

this takes a Proc.

For a function you do it like this

```
 public static string GetLine(Function<(string, int)> passedFunc, otherParms) // etc
```

Then you can call passedFunc in your GetLine procedure and get the tuple back.